# SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing <appname> for app installation

Tags: ios, voip

During update of the app to new version I see that iOS kills application. I see in logs:

```
Jul  2 18:20:40  SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing com.myapp.app for app installation
Jul  2 18:20:40  itunesstored[97] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: com.myapp.app (Placeholder)
Jul  2 18:20:40  backboardd[28] <Warning>: pid_suspend failed for [325]: Unknown error: -1, Unknown error: -1
Jul  2 18:20:40  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.myapp.app[0x11d1]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jul  2 18:20:40  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.myapp.app[0x11d1]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Jul  2 18:20:40  networkd[81] <Warning>: No attributes found for PID=325
Jul  2 18:20:40  itunesstored[97] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: com.myapp.app (Placeholder) withPhase:1
Jul  2 18:20:40  lsd[76] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Active; fractionCompleted=0.579990> to 1
Jul  2 18:20:40  installd[63] <Notice>: 0x283000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/1823728027110056877/-3508334369307939928" requested by itunesstored
Jul  2 18:20:41  installd[63] <Notice>: 0x283000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.myapp.app
Jul  2 18:20:41  installd[63] <Notice>: 0x283000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 1.03s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.38s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 1.41s
Jul  2 18:20:41  lsd[76] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Jul  2 18:20:41  itunesstored[97] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.myapp.app.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Finished; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Jul  2 18:20:41  lsd[76] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation ended for app com.myapp.app
Jul  2 18:20:42  lsd[76] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for com.myapp.app, it may have been removed
Jul  2 18:20:42  SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: nike-ipod is static and will never generate a notification
Jul  2 18:20:42  SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: still-camera is static and will never generate a notification
Jul  2 18:20:42  SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: magnetometer is static and will never generate a notification
Jul  2 18:20:42  SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: any-telephony is static and will never generate a notification
Jul  2 18:20:42  SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: stand-alone-contacts is static and will never generate a notification
Jul  2 18:20:42  kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[331] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/2493C106-296D-459B-9499-3CFE5FC05BFB (sandbox)
Jul  2 18:20:42  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.myapp.app[0x9d25]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jul  2 18:20:42  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.myapp.app[0x9d25]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds
Jul  2 18:20:42  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.myapp.app[0x9d25]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Jul  2 18:20:42  networkd[81] <Warning>: No attributes found for PID=331
Jul  2 18:20:42  itunesstored[97] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.myapp.app.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Finished; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Jul  2 18:20:42  lsd[76] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:userInfo.installState could not find parent progress for com.myapp.app, it may have been removed
Jul  2 18:
```

As I understand it is normal behaviour of iOS (I check update of other apps and see that they are also killed during update).

```
11:23 Jul  3 11:18:14 Sergey-Demchekos-iPhone SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing ua.slando for app installation
11:23 Jul  3 11:18:16 Sergey-Demchekos-iPhone SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing com.tripomatic.spainportugalapp for app installation
11:23 Jul  3 11:18:20 Sergey-Demchekos-iPhone SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing com.pineapple.Tenerife for app installation
```

Now the questions. Firstly, I am bit confused of these lines. Does it mean that I have problems during killing the app which I have to fix?:

```
Jul  2 18:20:30  SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing com.myapp.app for app installation
Jul  2 18:20:30  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.myapp.app[0xacc2]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jul  2 18:20:30  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.myapp.app[0xacc2]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

Secondly, If iOS kills app (btw it is VOIP), it is not run again until user explicitly runs icon of it on SpringBoard. Do I have any handler which will be called before app is killed in order to schedule local notification and remind user to run app again?